# vectorizing forward-looking function pandas dataframe

Tags: python, r, numpy, pandas, vectorization

I want to make a "strange" calculation on a DataFrame (could be thought as a Series) in pandas. The DataFrame has to be considered as a time-series or similar (order of elements is important).

- Given a value at index[i] (value[i])
- Given a step (e.g. 1) [an integer or real number]
- Given a multiplier rr (e.g. 2) [an integer or real number]

Look *forward* at elements [i:] and assign to value[i] a "class" of:

- +1 if the ensuing values reach a level of value[i] + step * rr *before* reaching value[i] - step
- -1 if the ensuing values reach a level of value[i] - step * rr *before* reaching value[i] + step
- 0 in each other cases (i.e. when ensuing values touch value[i] - step *and then* value[i] + step or vice-versa.

I know it sounds crazy. Just imagine a random walk with +1/-1 steps. A sequence like:

- 0, 1, 2 will be assigned to class +1 (it can also be 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 2)
- 0, -1, -2 will be assigned to class -1 (it can also be 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, -1, -1, -1, -2)
- 0, + 1, 0, -1 or 0, -1, 0, 0, -1, 0, 1 and the like will be class 0.

I have solved it the "classical" (and perhaps not-so-pythonic) way by defining a function:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def FindClass(inarr, i=0, step=0.001, rr=2):
    j = 0
    foundClass = None
    while i+j < len(inarr) - 1:
        j += 1
        if inarr[i+j] >= inarr[i] + step:
            direction = 1
            break
        if inarr[i+j] <= inarr[i] - step:
            direction = -1
            break

    while i+j < len(inarr)-1:
        j += 1
        if direction == 1 and inarr[i+j] >= inarr[i] + (step * rr):
            foundClass = 1
            break
        elif direction == 1 and inarr[i+j] <= inarr[i] - step:
            foundClass = 0
            break
        elif direction == -1 and inarr[i+j] <= inarr[i] - (step * rr):
            foundClass = -1
            break
        elif direction == -1 and inarr[i+j] >= inarr[i] + step:
            foundClass = 0
            break
    if foundClass is None:
        foundClass = np.nan

    return foundClass
```

and then iterating over it:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    steps = np.random.randint(-1, 2, size= 10000)

    randomwalk = steps.cumsum(0)
    rc = pd.DataFrame({'rw':randomwalk, 'result': np.nan})

    for c in range(0, len(rc)-1):
        rc.result[c] = FindClass(rc.rw, i=c, step=1)

    print rc
```

On my Laptop (and running python 2.7) I get a profiling which is not "too" bad for a 10000-elements series:

```
python -m cProfile -s cumulative fbmk.py
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 10000 entries, 0 to 9999
Data columns (total 2 columns):
result    9996  non-null values
rw        10000  non-null values
dtypes: float64(1), int32(1)
         932265 function calls (929764 primitive calls) in 2.643 seconds

   Ordered by: cumulative time

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    0.106    0.106    2.646    2.646 fbmk.py:1(<module>)
     9999    0.549    0.000    1.226    0.000 fbmk.py:4(FindClass)
   158062    0.222    0.000    0.665    0.000 series.py:616(__getitem__)
        2    0.029    0.014    0.561    0.281 __init__.py:3(<module>)
   158062    0.226    0.000    0.443    0.000 index.py:718(get_value)
    19998    0.070    0.000    0.442    0.000 frame.py:2082(__getattr__)
    19998    0.111    0.000    0.331    0.000 frame.py:1986(__getitem__)
```

The question is:

**Does anybody see a possibility of vectorizing this function in pandas/numpy in a way that is improving performance?**

If the thing is doable with less efforts in R, it would be good too!

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: It's not vectorising, but maybe you can write the function `findClass` in cython?

Comment: Yes, of course this is a possibility. The question here is mostly due to the fact that this is a row-by-row repetitive task, and people usually say that with pandas and similar you must "think vectorial", avoiding loops... I tried, but didn't manage!

Comment: Besides my idea in my answer, I think you'd gain substantial speed from rewriting your function to take advantage of the conditionals. You're putting long conditionals inside a while loop, but your logic allows you to exclude many of the options much of the time. That will cause much less code to execute and probably get you a factor of 2-4 in execution time.

Comment: Maybe the shift function could be useful for you, check it out: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the properties of your problem, you could use `np.where` to find where the levels are crossed and classify the time series.

The big downside here is the `np.where` will give you every index where the time series is above `value[i] + step`, etc., which will potentially turn a linear-time algorithm into a quadratic-time algorithm. Depending on the size of the problems you'll be processing, I expect that you'll gain a lot in the prefactor; you may even end up ahead with the quadratic-time numpy solution.

From poking around, the "find the first index" equivalent of `np.where` is still a requested feature.